# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'left', root is not considered a node

Tags: python-3.x, tree, binary-tree

I have the following code. On the first case, I create a tree in my main function, giving only the root, and I want the function "generate" to generate a tree. On the second case, I have a function that prints how the nodes will be visited in a level-order search of a tree. The problem is, although I make the tree the same way for both, when I try running 'generate' I get error message 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'left'
(The nodes have strings in them)

Can someone help me? Thanks

```
def generate(self, start):
    if start is None:
        return

    queue = Queue()
    queue.enqueue(start)

    counter=0
    while counter < 10:
        node = queue.dequeue()  
        if node.left is None:
            node.left = node.value + 'h'
        queue.enqueue(node.left)

        if node.right is None:
            node.right = node.value + 't'
        queue.enqueue(node.right)   

        counter+=1

def levelorder_print(self, start):
    if start is None:
        return

    queue = Queue()
    queue.enqueue(start)

    traversal = ""
    while len(queue) > 0:
        traversal += str(queue.peek()) + "-"
        node = queue.dequeue()
        if node.left:
            queue.enqueue(node.left)
        if node.right:
            queue.enqueue(node.right)

    return traversal
```

Comment: `queue.dequeue()` returns a string and the code treat it like an object.

Comment: But then why does it treat it like a node ( as I want it to ) in the level_order print function?

Comment: I also checked, and start.left works, but for some reason after dequeue, it no longer treats it like a node in the generate function, although it works in the levelorder_print function

Comment: You set the string in it when doing `node.left = node.value + 'h'` -> and then you enqueue then as string -> therefor the node are a strings...

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured it out too after a while, I had to put node(node.value +'h')